# net-snmp subagent: why 1 getnext request was processed 2 times?

Tags: net-snmp

Ok, maybe title can not say my question clear ...... following is the details.

I've written a subagent by net-snmp APIs. It works well for processing `get` request,
but for a `getnext` request, it responses 2 times.

example:

```
there are 3 scalars in my mib file, whose names are : var_1, var_2, var_3
now, I send a `get-next` request of var_1`s oid for getting var_2`s value
with mib-browser.and in the subagent, a function named `handle_var_2` was
defined for processing request of `var_2`, and in the function,
i can capture 2 `get` request in 'MODE_GET'.
```

Why does this occured ? Thank you everyone!

Comment: Can you confirm via tcpdump/Wireshark that only _one_ SNMP request is being sent when you perform your "getnext" test?  Client applications have been known to do stranger things than send two requests.